# Locked object found on oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection

Tags: java, database, multithreading, oracle

I am using JMC to perform application profiling and I did not see any locked/thread contention as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]
[image]
[image]
I ran the SQL below (every few secs) also did not return any result.

```
select 
   (select username from v$session where sid=a.sid) blocker,
   a.sid,
   ' is blocking ',
   (select username from v$session where sid=b.sid) blockee,
   b.sid
from 
   v$lock a, 
   v$lock b
where 
   a.block = 1
and 
   b.request > 0
and 
   a.id1 = b.id1
and 
   a.id2 = b.id2;
```

What could be the caused of a lock database connection? Could it be database record/table locks?

Below is the thread dump which I have extracted during the execution of my program when it seems to be running forever.

```
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:283)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:103)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:230)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:175)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:100)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:85)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:123)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:79)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1122)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1099)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:863)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1153)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1275)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3620)
    - locked <0x00000007af3423c0> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure about your concerns. When you're saying that your thread is running forever, do you mean that a particular SQL-query takes too long to return the result? Because otherwise there's nothing in the present data to worry about.

Comment: There is a function which takes 5 minutes to complete. I am trying to find out where is the bottleneck.

Comment: Have you tracked the problem down to a particular SQL-query that is executed by the dumped thread for too long? Or it's just a guess because there's the word `locked` in its dump and you thought that it meant some kind of blocking?

Comment: I thought there is some kind of blocking at the database level , when I saw the locked connection. since you have explained that this locked is a synchronize block of code, I guess I have to look elsewhere for the bottleneck

Comment: If you can track that those five mins are spent on executing a single DB query and there're no locks on the DB level, it might mean that the result dataset is very large or the network is slow. Also take a look at Hot Methods, that's usually the first place to look in such situations.

Comment: Ok, I will take a look at the hot methods. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: How can I tell if the network is slow? I am running the test from my laptop, and the Windows resource monitor shows the network utilization is avg around 25%

Comment: First thing to do is to find where those five minutes go to. It might not be the network (that was just one possibility of many). Maybe you'll find that all the time goes to one SQL-query that needs optimization. Maybe it will be some IO. Maybe you'll find that the query result set is processed incorrectly and slowly. Those are just guesses until you find exactly what methods take how long when you see a 5-minute delay. Here, Hot Methods might help. It will show you the methods that take too long to execute.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will look into it and hopefully get some leads to the performance issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're confusing database locks with Java locks here. JMC only shows you the locks inside your Java program (synchronized blocks, waits etc), it knows nothing about what's going on inside your DB. Your SQL-query only shows the locks on the DB level (table locks, row locks etc) and knows nothing about the locks inside your Java program. Those are absolutely different areas and absolutely different locks.

What you have here is a dump of a thread that holds a lock on the object of type `T4CConnection` with the address `0x7af3423c0`. It only means that this thread is in the process of executing a code inside some `synchronized(connection)` block. That's all. The thread is not blocked by other threads (otherwise its state wouldn't be `RUNNABLE`, it would be `WAITING` or `BLOCKED`). It's running and reading something from a network socket (probably, the response from the DB).

Such behaviour is absolutely normal. The DB driver does synchronization on the connection instance while it's in the process of executing an SQL-query to not allow other threads to use it in parallel.

There's nothing you should worry about on this screenshot and in this thread dump.

Comment: I have the same issue and it is absolutely not normal. Threads are randomly locked processing sql query for ever. One by one, and on the end there are no more free threads left and as result system is down. Our system can run against oracle or mssql database. Such problem occurs only with oracle jdbc driver (currently ojdbc6, but tested with ojdbc8 also and same result) and it never happens with mssql. The ReadTimeout property slightly helps, but not solves the problem.