# Threads hang while reading from socket . Is it related to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8049846?

Tags: java, sockets, java-8

It seems there was bug in jdk and it fixed in updated version , as per [link](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8049846).

How can i sure that this is the same issue and once i update jdk it will solve the issue.

Currently we are using jdk1.8_25 , is it fixed in jdk1.8_144?

Below is stack trace (thread dump)

```
ajp-bio-8010-exec-4225" prio=5 tid=0x123964 nid=0x1e43c RUNNABLE (JNI Native Code) - stats: cpu=13562 blk=-1 wait=-1
 java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:283)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:103)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:230)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:175)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:100)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:85)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:123)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:79)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1122)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1099)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1010)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1315)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
     - locked oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@448fbe18
```

Comment: have you considered "at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
     - locked oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@448fbe18" looks like something related to oracle

Comment: Is there any indicator that there should be a timeout?

Comment: No , becoz we are just running very simple query.

Comment: Some more details :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39200259/locked-object-found-on-oracle-jdbc-driver-t4cconnection

Answer (score 1):

this issue have been fixed long back in jdk9 and back ported to jdk8 as well. Please download the latest jdk8 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html